# Wordpress - same query in category.php and in function.php, but different result

Tags: php, wordpress

Im new to wordpress but not to programming. I have a problem with when i'm calling this:

```
$args = array(
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'cat' => 5,
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
```

And then do the loop, I get some results on en query in the function.php page that I dont get on the category.php page.

I'm I missing something or doing it wrong?

**ANSWER:**

Found the answer -  the query on the category page had post_status = 'publish' by default and the query in the function.php had post_status = 'publish' OR post_status = 'future' OR post_status = 'draft' OR post_status = 'pending' as default, so the solution was to be more explicit in the $args and add 'post_status' => 'publish'.

Comment: What you want to do?  Tell me more information/

Comment: Ofcourse - sorry! What I want to do is on the category page show the latest post 0 - 10 with category id 5. Then I have created a load more button which I call with ajax and there I want to show news from 11 - 20 with category id 5, and next time they clicks load more 21 - 30 and so on :-)

Comment: Try this make a templete and create `WP_Query` list posts(with ajax functionality) and after this add `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` this function will be reset custom query.

Comment: Sorry, but I dont understand what you mean?

Comment: This is apparently correct. Can you show more of the places where you are using this code, and describe what are you getting in each case? Please update your question.

Comment: Yeah the solution to this question makes no sense to the details provided. Lots of information has been excluded. I feel that's the trend of  WordPress for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer - the query on the category page had post_status = 'publish' by default and the query in the function.php had post_status = 'publish' OR post_status = 'future' OR post_status = 'draft' OR post_status = 'pending' as default, so the solution was to be more explicit in the $args and add 'post_status' => 'publish'.